# backdrop-filter doesn't render with Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a simple header in a section named "navigation":

```
<section class="navigation">
    <header>
        ...
    </header>
</section>
```

The CSS filed linked contains this:

```
.navigation header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    backdrop-filter: blur(40px);
}
```

The grid is used to align three icons. The first is for a burger menu, the second is the logo and the last one is an action "Book Now".

***It renders perfectly on Google Chrome but with Safari it doesn't work at all.***

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers sometimes have rendering problems with the CSS especially safari. Try to use `-webkit-filter`. It will solve your problem most likely. If not, please update me.